# List assignment from child to parent

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list

I am trying to do this:

```
List<Parent> test = new List<Child>();
```

The complete code of my class is this:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Parent> test = new List<Child>();

        test.Add(new Child());

        test.Add(new AnotherChild());
    }
}

class Parent { }

class Child : Parent { }

class AnotherChild : Parent { }
```

Can someebody please explian me why this gives me this error:

> Error 2   Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'   d:\personal\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs    20  24  ConsoleApplication3

And why does this work?

```
Parent[] test = new Child[10];
List<Parent> result = test.ToList();
```

Thanks :)

--
Right:

Now I know why: List is compiled to `` List`1 `` and List to `` List`2 ``. And they have no relationship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** because the two types, `List<Parent>` and `List<Child>` is not [co-variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(VS.100).aspx).

Even though the generic parameter you pass in, `Child`, inherits `Parent`, the relationship is not carried into the closed List types. Thus, the resulting two List types are not interchangeable.

.Net 4.0 introduces co-variance/contra-variance. Your code will still not work with .Net 4.0 though, since neither the `List` class or the `IList` interface will be changed to be co-variant.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this because `List<Child>` isn't assignable to `List<Parent>`, even though `Child` *is* assignable to `Parent`. The `List<T>` type is invariant.

Is there any reason why you can't use something like this instead?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Parent> test = new List<Parent>();

    test.Add(new Child());

    test.Add(new AnotherChild());
}
```

Comment: This works, but I wanted to know the reason. Now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 List<Parent> test = new List<Child>().Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics in C# are invariant, meaning there is no subtype relationship among the different instances of a generic type.

Conceptually speaking, `List<Child>` can not be a subtype of `List<Parent>`, because you can insert an instance of `AnotherChild` into a `List<Parent>`, but not into a `List<Child>`.

Comment: Note that in C# 4 there will be *limited* generic variance. It wouldn't make any difference in this case, but you would be able to convert from `IEnumerable<Child>` to `IEnumerable<Parent>`.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you this artice (it has good description of covariance and contravariance.):
http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance