# What am I doing wrong when seeing "cannot convert expression to type while using a generic method"?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `List<GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>>` and a generic `Add<T>()` method with a constraint for `T` being a `GKComponent`.

Why can't I add an instance of `GKComponentSystem<T>` to my list? See code snipped below:

```
List<GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>> _systems = new List<GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>>();

public void AddSystem<T>(int position = -1) where T : GKComponent
{
    var system = new GKComponentSystem<T>();
    _systems.Add(system);
}
```

Error:

> Argument #1 cannot convert GameplayKit.GKComponentSystem<T> expression
>   to type GameplayKit.GKComponentSystem<GameplayKit.GKComponent>

That’s in the line `_systems.Add(system)`.

I thought I knew C#, but this is one of the situations where I'm happy to have StackOverflow - what the heck am I not understanding here?

`system` is a `GKComponentSystem<T>` and `T` must be a `GKComponent`, so `system` is a `GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>` and I should be able to add it to my list.

Here's `GKComponentSystem`:

`public class GKComponentSystem<T> : NSObject where T : GKComponent`

Its `T` is also a `GKComponent`...

Is this about contravariance (a topic I definitely have to learn more about)?

Comment: Yes it is about contravariance. If you added a example of how `T` is used in `GKComponentSystem<T>` we could show you a example of why it does not work or how to work around it (depending on how `T` is used)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain added more info. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simpler example:

```
 class Parent
 {
 }

 class Child : Parent
 {
 }


 class GenericClass<T> 
 {
 }


 Parent p;
 p = new Child();  // A child inherits from Parent, so this is allowed.

 GenericClass<Parent> gp;

 gp = new GenericClass<Child>();  // Not allowed! GenericClass<Child> does not inherit from GenericClass<Parent>
```

In your example, the fact that `T` inherits from `GKComponent`, does not translate to a rule that `GKComponentSystem<T>` can be converted to `GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>`.

So lets apply this to Lists now.

```
List<Parent> l = new List<Parent>();
l.Add(new Child());  // A child can be converted to a Parent, this is OK


List<GenericClass<Parent>> gl = new List<GenericClass<Parent>>();

gl.Add(new GenericClass<Child>()); // A GenericClass<Child> does not convert to GenericClass<Parent>, so this is not allowed.
```

If you really want this to work, you can define a generic interface. These allow you to specify generic parameters with `out` as follows:

```
 interface IGenericClass<out T>
 {
 }

 class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T>
 {
 }

 IGenericClass<Child> gcChild = new GenericClass<Child>();
 IGenericClass<Parent> gcParent = gcChild; // This is allowed!

 var l = new List<IGenericClass<Parent>>();
 l.Add(new GenericClass<Child>()); // Also allowed
```

So to apply this to your example:

```
 interface IGKComponentSystem<out T> 
 {
 }

 class GKComponentSystem<T> : IGKComponentSystem
 {
 }

 List<IGKComponentSystem<GKComponent>> _systems = new List<IGKComponentSystem<GKComponent>(); 

 // Should work from there...  
 public void AddSystem<T>(int position = -1) where T : GKComponent
 {
    var system = new GKComponentSystem<T>();
    _systems.Add(system);
 }
```

Comment: Is this really a simpler version of what I have? I don't convert `GKComponent` itself. I want to add a subclass of `GKComponent` into a `List` of `GKComponents?. And this works when not using generics. I could create a `List<Parent>()` and Add() a `Child`.

Comment: @Krumeler - That's because Child inherits from Parent. `GenericClass<Child>` does not inherit from `GenericClass<Parent>`

Comment: I know. That's what I mean: I have a `List<Parent>` and want to add a `Child`. Now replace "Parent" with `GKComponent` and "Child" with `SubclassOfGkComponent`. I have list of `GKComponent` and add something that I constrain to a `GKComponent`.

Comment: Are you're saying: a `Child` is a `Parent` but a `TenYearOld-Child` is not a `TenYearOld-Parent`? Is that how we could explain it?

Comment: @Krumelur - Errm, not really, but if it works for you :-) I've added more to my question, showing you how to get this to work.

Comment: Haha...it's kinda hard to write what I meant. But I get what you're saying. Since I don't have `GKComponentSystem` under my control, I won't be able  to us the generic interfaces. So I'll have to rethink my design.

Comment: @Krumelur do you expect `List<Cats>` to start deriving from `List<Animal>` even if `List` never knew about this types... Also what behavior you'd expect from `List<Cats>.Add` (that now somehow need to support adding dogs)? (there are many questions on this topic like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396747/list-assignment-from-child-to-parent because it is simply hard to rationalize that `A:B` does not mean `G<A>:G<B>` )

Comment: @Krumelur when working with generics and trying to figure out inheritance just replace the < and > with _. Now if you had `List_GKComponentSystem_GKComponent__` and it's `Add(GKComponentSystem_GKComponent_ item)` method, why do you think a class named `GKComponentSystem_GKComponentSubTypeA_` would be allowed to be used when `GKComponentSystem_GKComponentSubTypeA_` does not inherit from `GKComponentSystem_GKComponent_`, The only relation the two classes have is they both inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing your custom types with BCL types:

```
List<List<object>> _systems = new List<List<object>>();

public void AddSystem<T>(int position = -1) where T : class
{
    var system = new List<T>();
    _systems.Add(system);
}
```

Now, suppose this were valid and I were to call `AddSystem<string>();`. This would create a `List<string>`, and add it to `_systems`.

Now, suppose I call `_systems[0].Add(1);`. There's nothing preventing this. `_systems` is a `List<List<object>>`, therefore `_systems[0]` is a `List<object>`, therefore its `Add` method accepts any object.

But what I created was a `List<string>`, not a `List<object>`. It shouldn't be possible to add an `int` to it.

The only way this can be rejected by the compiler is by making the `List<string>`-to-`List<object>` conversion invalid. Or in your case, the `GKComponentSystem<T>` to `GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>` conversion.

> Is this about contravariance (a topic I definitely have to learn more about)?

Sort of. Interface and delegate types can specify that some additional guarantees are made. The `IEnumerable<string>`-to-`IEnumerable<object>` conversion safe, and allowed for types that include the appropriate annotation. But it's not available for class types, and what you can put in such an interface is a bit restricted, anything that could potentially be unsafe is disallowed.

If what you want to put in your `GKComponentSystem` only allows reads, meaning it doesn't have the problem `List` does, you could make an `IGKComponentSystem<T>` interface, and store a `List<IGKComponentSystem<GKComponent>>`, and add a `IGKComponentSystem<T>` instance to that without issues.

If what you want to put in your `GKComponentSystem` also allows writes (such as an `Add` method), then the conversion is inherently unsafe and you'll need to re-think your design.